# Record all xmls from JMS queue before they get processed by trigger

Tags: xml, queue, jms, message-queue, messaging

Has anyone had any luck with a tool that can save all xmls (as say .txt or .xml files doesn't matter) that arrive on a websphere MQ before they get processed off the queue by a JMS trigger (without disabling the trigger or tweaking its settings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@toop: you can create and configure MQ exits to do that